# How to model simply an objective piecewise linear?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I want to model a linear optimization problem where the objective is piecewise linear i.e.

$ f(x) = A*x+b $ if $x \leq x^*$

$ f(x) = C*x+d $ if $x > x^*$

How can I model it as a linear objective that could "automatically" affect the right value depending on $x$ value (i.e. : how to "give it" to a solver) ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: I'm  not sure what you mean by "model" here.  Generally a function as you give here **is** a model for some situation.  You seem to be saying you want to write it as a single formula.  One way to do that would be to use the "Heaviside step function", H(x) which is defined to be 0 if x is less than 0, 1 if x is greater than or equal to 0.  Then you can write f(x)= Ax+ b+ H(x- x*)(Cx+ d- Ax+ b).  Or course, your "solver" might not recognize H(x).

Comment: Read https://orinanobworld.blogspot.fr/2010/10/piecewise-linear-functions-in-math.html and https://orinanobworld.blogspot.fr/2011/08/piecewise-linear-functions-redux.html

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks for these references, I think they'll help me